# How do I select the first row on this site with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-scraping

I am trying to select the first row that has the channel, artist, song, etc. I am not sure how to select it?

This is the site:

http://www.dogstarradio.com/search_playlist.php?artist=&title=&channel=51&month=&date=&shour=&sampm=&stz=&ehour=&eampm=

And I have tried

$("td:contains('51')") but that does not work.

Ultimately I want to be able to select the rows that follow.

---- Here is the html that I am trying to grab but there is no real unique identifier such as a class or element and there are more than one table, row, and table data

```
    <center>This search includes data from 12:00:00 AM 9/30/2013 to 6:05:18 PM 10/6/2013<br>

    <table><tbody><tr><td colspan="5"><div id="light" class="white_content"></div></td></tr><tr><td>
&nbsp;</td><td colspan="3">Search results 1 to 50 of 2441 total matches</td><td><a href="search_playlist.php?artist=&amp;title=&amp;channel=51&amp;month=&amp;date=&amp;shour=&amp;sampm=&amp;stz=&amp;ehour=&amp;eampm=&amp;resultcount=2441&amp;page=1">Next<br>Page</a></td></tr><tr><td class="channel">Channel</td><td class="channel">Artist</td><td class="channel">Title</td><td class="channel">Date</td><td class="channel">Time</td></tr>
```

The Line below: (which is in the middle of the top and bottom html)

```
<tr><td>51</td><td>Swanky Tunes+Dvbbs+Eitro</td><td><a href="#Swanky+Tunes%2BDvbbs%2BEitroWe+Know" onclick="seeqpodSearch('Swanky+Tunes%2BDvbbs%2BEitro','We+Know')">We Know</a></td><td>10/5/2013</td><td>3:00:05 AM</td></tr>
```

--

```
<tr><td>51</td><td>Stefan Biniak</td><td><a href="#Stefan+BiniakJohnny+Rotten+Bootleg" onclick="seeqpodSearch('Stefan+Biniak','Johnny+Rotten+Bootleg')">Johnny Rotten Bootleg</a></td><td>10/5/2013</td><td>2:54:46 AM</td></tr>
<tr><td>51</td><td>Tiesto+Dyro</td><td><a href="#Tiesto%2BDyroParadise" onclick="seeqpodSearch('Tiesto%2BDyro','Paradise')">Paradise</a></td><td>10/5/2013</td><td>2:50:12 AM</td></tr>
<tr><td>51</td><td>@ClubLifeRadio</td><td><a href="#%40ClubLifeRadioTop+40+Countdown" onclick="seeqpodSearch('%40ClubLifeRadio','Top+40+Countdown')">Top 40 Countdown</a></td><td>10/5/2013</td><td>2:49:48 AM</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Comment: Copying the **relevant portions of the code** (a small sample of the table) here instead of merely linking to the whole thing increases your chances of getting a meaningful answer.

Comment: Are you trying to scrape this in client side JavaScript from your site? If so you might encounter issues with being blocked to avoid cross site scripting security concerns.

Comment: Ok added the changes, and in terms of scraping, I am trying to do it from node.js on the server side, using cheerio and request to load the document and then I want to just grab the row to pull out the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var row = $('td.channel:first-child').parent().next();
```

will get you the entire row.

**edit**

To get the following rows, something along the lines of

```
While(row.not(':last-child')){
    Do stuff. 
    row = row.next();
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting the class of channel from?

Comment: The row before your desired row, it has 5 cells, all of class "channel". Is the most unique thing about this table so I used that to gauge where your first desired line is.

Could equally count the fourth row from the top of the table

Comment: awesome did not realize that, and it worked but how would I pick out the following children as well, besides the first-child

Comment: As in the following rows? I would save a variable to that first row, run a while loop checking to see if you are on the last child, and if not process the .next() from the row you've got.

Comment: Example edited into the answer

Comment: Thanks a lot, by the way it worked. I just needed to understand how, I am not grabbing it correctly